# -80 being added to bounds.origin.x for UIView

Tags: ios, ios4

I have a series of UIViews inside a UIScrollView which I am attempting to resize when the root view controller receives willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:duration:

Here is the code...

(Panel is just an extended UIView; panels is an NSMutableArray of Panels held by an extended UIScrollView)

```
for(Panel * panel in panels)
{
  panel.bounds = CGRectMake(panel.bounds.origin.x,
                            panel.bounds.origin.y,
                            self.bounds.size.width,
                            panel.bounds.size.height);
}

NSLog(@"%@", [panels description]);
```

The `self.bounds.size.width` is the UIScrollView (I've extended the class).

Here is the result of NSLog when the device is oriented to **landscape**...

```
"<Panel: 0x74324d0; frame = (-80 0; 480 50); animations = { bounds=<CABasicAnimation: 0xe1339d0>; }; layer = <CALayer: 0x7432530>>",
"<Panel: 0x7435ce0; frame = (-80 53; 480 50); animations = { bounds=<CABasicAnimation: 0xe133a90>; }; layer = <CALayer: 0x7435d40>>",
"<Panel: 0x7438e20; frame = (-80 106; 480 50); animations = { bounds=<CABasicAnimation: 0xe133ab0>; }; layer = <CALayer: 0x7438e80>>",
"<Panel: 0x7438eb0; frame = (-80 159; 480 50); animations = { bounds=<CABasicAnimation: 0x714f890>; }; layer = <CALayer: 0x7438f10>>",
"<Panel: 0x7438f40; frame = (-80 212; 480 50); animations = { bounds=<CABasicAnimation: 0x742ffd0>; }; layer = <CALayer: 0x7438fa0>>"
```

And when it's changed back to **portrait**...

```
"<Panel: 0x7480350; frame = (0 0; 320 50); animations = { bounds=<CABasicAnimation: 0x74a3b40>; }; layer = <CALayer: 0x74803b0>>",
"<Panel: 0x7483c90; frame = (0 53; 320 50); animations = { bounds=<CABasicAnimation: 0x74a3bd0>; }; layer = <CALayer: 0x7483cf0>>",
"<Panel: 0x7486dd0; frame = (0 106; 320 50); animations = { bounds=<CABasicAnimation: 0x74a3c60>; }; layer = <CALayer: 0x7486e30>>",
"<Panel: 0x7486e60; frame = (0 159; 320 50); animations = { bounds=<CABasicAnimation: 0x74a3cf0>; }; layer = <CALayer: 0x7486ec0>>",
"<Panel: 0x7486ef0; frame = (0 212; 320 50); animations = { bounds=<CABasicAnimation: 0x74a3d80>; }; layer = <CALayer: 0x7486f50>>"
```

I don't see any reason why the bounds.origin.x should ever be anything other than what it starts at (0). It must be something obvious, but I just can't see it - maybe some fresh eyes will see what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewPG_iPhoneOS/WindowsandViews/WindowsandViews.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009503-CH2-SW6 
Have a look at apple guide

Comment: I've already read that. Is there supposed to be something glaringly obvious in it that I've missed?

Comment: you have to set frame not bounds because as your view resizes its subviews, its frame changes in its parent view. Try this in xib. create a view and add full screen imageView on it. then put that imageView inside a scrollview, you will see that frame of imageView is changed.

Comment: Thank you! I had thought that as bounds is in its own world with coordinates, that the x and y being 0 would still align it to the superviews frame...but I guess this is not the case. If you want to formulate an answer out of your comments I'll choose it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should have a look at [Difference between frame and bounds](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewPG_iPhoneOS/WindowsandViews/WindowsandViews.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009503-CH2-SW6)

You have to set frame not bounds, as setting the bounds changes frame of view in its superView.

Hope this will help.

Comment: Difference between frame and size or difference between frame and bounds? Remember I was trying to change the size not just the position